# Fastest way to request API with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, binance

I'm trying to request Binance API https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ping in a NodeJS app in order to make some trades. I'm using axios to request the API

```
const testBinanceAPIResponseTime = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ping");
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

I added an interceptor to measure response time

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((x) => {
  x.meta = x.meta || {};
  x.meta.requestStartedAt = new Date().getTime();
  return x;
});

axios.interceptors.response.use((x) => {
  console.log(
    `Execution time for: ${x.config.url} - ${
      new Date().getTime() - x.config.meta.requestStartedAt
    } ms`
  );
  return x;
});
```

My issue is the response time is always around `220 ms` wether I deploy my code on Heroku EU or Heroku US. According to "documentation", requests from US should be a way faster (~ `10 ms`) than EU since there is some Binance servers there. Is there a way to improve that response time by using another lib or another pattern?

Comment: You can try to cache response if possible.

Comment: Are you sure you can have a response in 10 ms. Have you seen this kind of response time anywhere like In a browser or somewhere in other apps?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that's what people is saying here with Python https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/189#issuecomment-813423212 @NamitPiriya

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to do a request with `Postman` for example or a tool to test the real speed of it.

After it, I would not use the `axios` Npm, use a regular `fetch request`.

Also, check the speed of your Heroku server(the difference between local and on server)

Comment: I tried locally with NodeJS and I got the same response time. I tried with Postman on my computer and I got the same response time. What do yo mean with "Speed of your Heroku server" ?

Comment: I think that's you are not the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: try api tests performance but i think the probleme is the API

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm testing it with my computer from EU

Answer (score 0):

**Your Data can not travel faster than the speed of the light.**
So If you have 3000 km distance that is equal to 3 * 10^6 meters and the speed of light is 3 * 10 ^ 8 meter/second `timeTaken = distance/velocity` which is `3*10^6 / 3*10^8 =10^-2 (.01 s)` which is 10 ms (10 * 10 ^ -3). So when you count rount trip time that is sent and recieved it will be double 20 ms that is the fastest you can get. I have not included routing and other times And also apis have their own response time (processing time of your request).If the heroku server is far away from your binance server even though its in america, you can not get the desired speed.